# Inner join on tables not directly related

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

Okay so I have three tables with these fields (of course there are more non relevant):

**full_table**
attribute
articleID

**main_table**
articleID

**other_table**
attribute

So in full_table there is the full list of "articleID" and its related "attribute". In main_table there are only some articleID. In other_table there are only some of those "attribute".

What I want is to get ONLY those articles whose attribute are in other_table AND whose articleID are in main_table.

EDIT: Some visual help of the description

[image: problem description]

Problem is my query returns also a lot of them that are not in other_table.

Query is as follows:

```
SELECT full_table.attribute, main_table.articleID FROM main_table
INNER JOIN full_table ON full_table.articleID = main_table.articleID 
INNER JOIN other_table ON other_table.attribute = full_table.attribute
```

EDIT2: I have tested the sample pic and code on sql fiddle and works as desired, so the problem must come from the added complexity of the real query, I'll keep researching the source of the issue.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Your query would appear to do what you want:  "get ONLY those articles whose attribute are in other_table".

Comment: Thank you Gordon, here you go with the sample and desired result ;)

Comment: . . You should delete the question, because it was caused by a misunderstanding.

Comment: I can't sorry, it doesn't let me when has answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that it was returning the same rows 3 times each, thus confusing me because the number of rows was much larger than expected. But the query was filtering propperly.

Solved it by adding a GROUP BY to all the selected items.

Solution was:

```
SELECT full_table.attribute, main_table.articleID FROM main_table
INNER JOIN full_table ON full_table.articleID = main_table.articleID 
INNER JOIN other_table ON other_table.attribute = full_table.attribute
GROUP BY full_table.attribute, main_table.articleID
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the foreign key relationships, so the example is clearer. However, at a glance, could you do something like:

```
SELECT ot.attribute,
       ft.articleId
FROM other_table ot
INNER JOIN full_table ft ON ot.attribute = ft.attribute;
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood.

```
DECLARE @full_table TABLE (articleID INT, attribute NVARCHAR(100))
DECLARE @main_table TABLE (articleID INT)
DECLARE @other_table TABLE (attribute NVARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @full_table VALUES (1,'attrib1'),(2,'attrib2'),(3,'attrib3'),(4,'attrib4'),(5,'attrib5')
INSERT INTO @main_table VALUES (2),(3),(5)
INSERT INTO @other_table VALUES ('attrib1'),('attrib2'),('attrib5')

SELECT a.* FROM @full_table as a
INNER JOIN @other_table as b ON a.attribute = b.attribute
```